# Rails deployment to Windows Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, postgresql, server

I am trying to serve up a Rails application to a Windows Server that runs on a PostgreSQL DB. Was wondering if anyone had any resources/experience that would help this *brutal* process. I keep running into the Nokogiri build problem where, I can successfully `bundle install` but then when I run `rake db:create` it throws this error:

```
'require': cannot load such file -- 'nokogiri\nokogiri' (LoadError)
```

Comment: Use docker? Why windows?

Comment: There are a lot of reasons why someone has to use Windows. Sometimes people just want to... An answer to a question shouldn't really ever be don't try it when there is an actual answer somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Nokogiri won't support windows and ruby 2.2.x until the next release (which should be very soon).
see flavorjones's [reply](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1256) and [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/nokogiri-talk/aJkGZz5bhRo/3yu3BNFPDgAJ)

> Hi all, I just emailed nokogiri-talk about a Windows release. If you don't subscribe, you should ... TL;DR we're going to get this out the door this week, honest. Thanks for your patience.

I believe there are issues because it doesn't suport native builds (relying on prebuilt DLLs instead.

Comment: Pretty much this. I recommend using 2.1.X, it's the best supported right now.